# "Permission denied" error when sending a query with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-lake-formation

### Want to Achieve

I would like to execute a SELECT statement in AWS Athena, but I am getting the following error.
Glue catalog is ready, meta information is ready, DDL can be displayed.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to make the query work properly.

```
SELECT * FROM "table_name" limit 10;
```

↓

```
Permission denied on S3 path: s3://backet_name/falder_name/db_name/table_name/parquet_name
```

error_message

```
"errorCode":"AccessDenied",
"errorMessage":"User: arn:aws:sts::<Account_ID>:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForLakeFormationDataAccess/AWSLF-00-AT-<Account_ID>-OSSm3ywcAP is not authorized to perform: kms:Decrypt on resource: arn:aws:kms:ap-northeast-1:<Account_ID>:key/○○ because no resource-based policy allows the kms:Decrypt action"
```

### Environment

On AWS
RDS snapshots are exported to S3 and crawled by Glue to create a data catalog.
In addition, we are using AWS LakeFormation to manage the data.

### Setup

##### AWServiceRoleForLakeFormationDataAccess

"AWServiceRoleForLakeFormationDataAccess" is set as the crawler's service role.
Policies allowed for this role include.
・AWSGlueServiceRole
・AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
・kms-decrypt-policy
・LakeFormationGetPolicy

kms-decrypt-policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

LakeFormationGetPolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lakeformation:GetResourceLFTags",
                "lakeformation:GetDataAccess",
                "lakeformation:ListLFTags",
                "lakeformation:GetLFTag"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Athena Execution User(datalake_user)

Attached Policies
・AmazonAthenaFullAccess
・AmazonS3FullAccess
・KMSFullAccessPolicy

##### Lake Formation > Permissions

[image: イメージ説明]

##### LF-Tags

[image: イメージ説明]

##### AWS Lake Formation > Grant permissions > Grant data permissions

[image: イメージ説明]

[image: イメージ説明]

##### AWS Lake Formation > Databases > db_sample_for_athena

[image: イメージ説明]

Answer (score 2):

Attaching KMS to AWServiceRoleForLakeFormationDataAccess solved the problem.

Comment: Which KMS permission did you add?